# Entity Configuration in MVC web Application using EntityFramework

Tags: .net, entity-framework

i wan to configure entities mean relations of entities many to many relation foreign key relation using entity framework, I am using repository pattern with unity of work.

Kindly guide me how to configure entities in MVC using entity frame work in code first approach. I am using mvc4

Comment: https://github.com/stefchri/ArticulatieOnderzoek this is an example of mine. Code first fluent API, UoW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use [Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx) for mapping configuration. That will keep your entities clean from database-related attributes.